# img-responsive failure by using IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to this and I'm building my first landinpage with the help of bootstrap.
So don't be mean to me ;)

I added a big picture with the width of 2400px and added the class "img-responsive" to make the suitable for every viewport. But in IE11 it does not work.
In Mozilla or Chrome there is no problem but I can not find any solution.
Can somebody give me some advice?

Thank you very much,
Tobi

Here is a example of the html:

```html
<img src="images/headerbild.png" alt="Flensboxx" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: A little code will be good for community members to start of with your problem and understand your problem context better.

Comment: Post the css related your problem

Comment: If you are talking about the max-width:100% in this image: `headerbild.png` try to replace for width:100%

Comment: maybe it is a problem with the main-picture `<div class="main-picture">
                        <img src="images/headerbild.png" alt="Flensboxx" class="img-responsive"/>` I thought the class "img-responsive" is there for making the image suitable for the right viewport.

Comment: The main-picture has a width of 2400 px.

Comment: No, this is the width of the image, in IE the max-width is relative to its original size, not to the size of the parent. Change `max-width` for `width`

Comment: Having problems with IE and Edge is normal and expected.

Comment: you are right :) Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just insert this in cover.css

```
.img-responsive{width: 100%;}
```

Comment: I did that a few seconds before you answered and it worked for me. Seems to be a bug. Many thanks for all your answers :) I will change the title so other persons can find the answer to the problem better. Because I was wrong with my description.

Answer (score 0):

In my case works with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

`.img-responsive{width: 100%;}`
 works for me by HudsonPH